# Grouping user actions into multiple sessions based on relative time

Tags: python, hive

I am trying to calculate the number of photo sessions (a group of photos taken around the same time) a user has. For this example let's just say a photo is part of a session if it was taken within 1000 seconds of the preceding photo by that user.

Originally I was planning to order pictures by time taken per uid and then comparing the times to the row above it, but I am not sure of the best way to do that in hive.

Is this possible, or would I have better luck doing this with another language like python?

e.g.

```
table of data:  
uid | pid | time_in_sec  
001 | 111 | 1000  
001 | 222 | 1250  
001 | 333 | 2200  
001 | 444 | 5000  
002 | 555 | 2000  
002 | 666 | 2500
```

outcome:

```
uid | num_sessions  
001 | 2  
002 | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hive udf feature to create session info table, so you can do the rest.

HIVE statement:

```
add file gen_session.py;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE session_info SELECT TRANSFORM(uid, ts) USING './gen_session.py' AS (uid, sid, start_ts, end_ts) FROM sample ;
```

gen_session.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

SESSION_GAP = 1000

sid = 0

last_uid = None
start_ts, end_ts = None, None

for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    info = line.split('\t')
    uid, ts = info[0], int(info[1].strip())

    # new session?
    if (last_uid != uid) or (last_uid == uid and ts - end_ts > SESSION_GAP):
        # write last session info
        if start_ts != None:
            print '\t'.join([str(x) for x in [uid, sid, start_ts, end_ts]])
        # assign new session
        sid += 1
        last_uid = uid
        start_ts = end_ts = ts
    end_ts = ts
print '\t'.join([str(x) for x in [uid, sid, start_ts, end_ts]])
```

Answer (score 0):

try below method.May be useful for you.
first,create tmp table:

```
use tmp ;
create table session_test(uid string,pid string,time_in_sec STRING) row format delimited    fields terminated by '|' ;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/a.txt' INTO TABLE session_test;
```

then,try below sql:

```
select uid,sum(if(time_in_sec - last_time>=1000,1,0))+1
from (
select a.uid,a.time_in_sec,max(if(b.time_in_sec<a.time_in_sec,b.time_in_sec,null))  last_time
from session_test a join session_test b
on (a.uid = b.uid)
group by a.uid,a.time_in_sec
) b
group by uid
```